# How are twips on a video projector calculated? Is there a possibility to configure?

Tags: ms-access, screen

My Ms Access(2010) database uses forms to display and manipulate data. Recently, when presenting these, I found out that the use of these forms on a video projector leads to a severe problem, the forms appear to be 'zoomed' in.

Therefore I have 2 questions, thanks for the answer!

1) How are twips on a video projector calculated? Theoretically this should depend on the distance between projector and screen, which woulnd't make too much sense. (I'd need this information to be able to explain the problem, thank you very very much)

2) How can this be configurated? Is it possible to use VBA or Win32 API to achieve this?

Comment: You have not given us much info. There are 1440 TWIPS per screen inch.  I have no idea how the beamer software works (had to google it to find out what it was). How does this interact with your computer ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, beamer=video projector, didn't know this is mistakeable

Comment: Only the forms and not the whole application?

Comment: Most likely, the maximum resolution of the video projector (prob 1024x768) is much less than the resolution of your screen. Change the screen resolution to match it, tweak your forms if they then need resizing, and then the two should match. BTW when I google beamer, it came up with a specific model of mobile phone, so I assumed you were trying to send the screen to a mobile phone!

Comment: no, this has nothing to do with resolution as twips do not care about. The resolution only affects ms access gui, but not the forms.

(when you google beamer on german google the first 5 pages are video projectors :))

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think this problem has anything to do with TWIPS or with the video projector. Any monitor (analogue, digital, projector, etc.)  shows the same picture if it has the same resolution. If you set the output of your computer to i.e. 1024 * 768 pixels and the output device (analogue or digital monitor, projector, etc.) uses the same native resolution then the picture will look the same on each device.
Access works in pixels. If you have a form optimized for a specific amount of pixels then this is what Access uses. If you have a higher resolution then form will not fill the screen and if you have a smaller resolution the form will not be completely shown on the screen.
I guess what happens is that you use on your PC an output of i.e. 1600 * 1200 pixels but your projector can’t show this correctly. So the projector tries to convert i.e. 1600*1200 to 1024*768 and this will never look good.
I think you have two options: Check the resolution which your projector expects and set your PC to the same resolution. Or change your application – or the projector.

Answer (score 0):

In line with what Edgar has suggested, regardless of the display type (projector, monitor etc...) the issue will remain the same. In this scenario, the problem is the form is designed for a given screen size, say 1600x900 (16:9) or 1920x1200 (16:10) or whatever you have chosen to design the form as.

The projector is likely not the same resolution as this. Many smaller projectors are either 1024x768 or 1280x720, both of which are likely smaller than your computer monitor in regards to resolution. While it is true that you could design the forms to the proper pixel dimension of the projector an easier way, that wouldn't require editing any content, would be to send the projector the same resolution that you have designed the forms to be.

For example, if your forms fit nicely on a 1920x1080 pixel space but your projector is 1024x768 then you could open display preferences on your computer and set the output to the projector to be 1920x1080. The projector will then scale the image to fit onto its 1024x768 panel.

There are many variables in here and you may run into equipment limitation with this approach, such as the projector not being capable of ingesting and scaling a given resolution which you are forcing into it. In that instance you could utilize a hardware video scaler inline between the computer and projector to perform the scaling operation for you. An example of a device capable of this would be a Barco ImagePro, though there are many other more cost-effective solutions on the market as well.